# Getting multiple data attributes from checkboxs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quiz I am making.

Some questions have multiple answers.

My html is as:

```
<div>Which problems equal 4?</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="qid" class="checks" data-correct="yes">2 + 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="qid" class="checks" data-correct="no">2 - 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="qid" class="checks" data-correct="yes">2 * 2<br />
```

I would like to alert if checked answers are both wrong or right.

Currently, my Javascript looks like this:

```
function checkMsResults(){
    var result = $('input[name="qid"]:checked').attr("data-correct");
    if(result == '1'){
        result = "Answer is Correct";
    }
    else if(result == '0'){
        result = "Answer is Not Correct";
    }
    else{
        result = "Please make a selection";
    }
    alert(result + ".");
}
```

This will alert only one selection.
Can someone teach me how to loop through each on so I can alert multiple selections?

Comment: where are you calling the function 'checkMsResults'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three inputs with the same id, you can't do that, id must be unique.

```js
function checkMsResults() {
  if ($('input[name="quid"]:checked').length === 0) {
    var result = "Please make a selection";
    alert(result);
    return;
  }
  $('input[name="quid"]:checked').each(function() {
    var result;
    if (this.getAttribute("data-correct") === "yes") {
      result = "Answer is Correct";
    } else {
      result = "Answer is Not Correct"
    }
    alert(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: The id's are actually php generated and are all different. I forgot to show the differences in the question.

Comment: I see that there is a .each that creates a loop for the if / else statement. Thank you, now I know.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up your original. Here's a jsfiddle that takes the answer of each and sticks all into an array off answers; you can do whatever you want with it after that...https://jsfiddle.net/r2xc22Ld/1/

```
function checkMsResults(){


var result = "";
var answers = [];
$('input[name="qid"]:checked').each(function() {
   answers.push($(this).attr('data-correct'));
});

//console.log(answers);
for(var i = 0; i< answers.length; i++){
    result += 'Question '+i+': ' + answers[i] +'\n';   
}
if(result==""){
    alert('make a selection...');
}else{
    alert(result);
}
```